# XCTest UI Test System PhotoAuth Alert error。[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil (NSInvalidArgumentException)

Tags: xcode, alert, xctest, uitest, springboard

```objectivec
// tap photo auth entrance
XCUIElement *collectionView = app.collectionViews.firstMatch;
XCUIElement *authCell = [collectionView.cells elementBoundByIndex:2];
[authCell tap];
    
// springboard click allow
XCUIApplication *springboard = [[XCUIApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.springboard"];
XCUIElement *button = [[springboard.alerts.firstMatch buttons] elementBoundByIndex:1];
BOOL exist = [button waitForExistenceWithTimeout:5];
XCTAssertEqual(exist, YES, @"photo auth alert not exist");
[button tap];
```

It works fine on my iphone12（iOS15.4）, but it not works on another iphone12-Pro（iOS15.4）

error:
*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil (NSInvalidArgumentException)

How should I solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Help..............

Comment: Restarting the iOS device resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Steps working for me :

1. close the iOS device or simulator
2. clean the build folder
3. clear the derived data
4. then open the iOS Device or simulator

you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Restarting iOS Device or simulator works for me